# Decrypting with AES256CBC Library doesn't return same value?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, aes

I'm trying to implement aes256 security to both Android, iOS and Web. In iOS part I'm using [this library](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/AES256CBC). But when I try to decrypt text with same password on [this website](http://aesencryption.net) or any other website or with googles aes.js file in html project. They don't give same result.
What am I missing? Thank you.

```
  let str = "emre"
    let password = "2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI"
    let encrypted = AES256CBC.encryptString(str, password: password)
    print(encrypted!)
    let decrypted = AES256CBC.decryptString(encrypted!, password: "2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI")
    print(decrypted!)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AES256CBC.encryptString(..)` methode you use, generates an IV and prepend the encrypted data with it. The `AES256CBC.decryptString(..)` methode then 
obtains the **IV** from the encrypted data before decrypting the message.

Take a look in the `encryptString` methody you are using. See the IV it's creating? The IV is a random bit of data given as input to AES encryp/decrypt when running in CBC mode. The IV is often pre-prended to the encrypted data (as this library did here), but this is not standardized across different libraries.

If you wan't to use this library together with other implementations, you need to handle this part yourself.

Also, the online web page you link, don't seem to support CBC mode, so try use another one, like [this](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what I need to do for the web side?

Comment: ı was looked that page but I couldn't find the output string. It also gives different value. I understand the case so I think I need to change my library from CBS to another usual one?